# slicing 3 dimensional array in neural network python

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

In line `X_train_1 = X_train[:,0:10081,:]` in the model below, slicing seems to involve 3-dimensional data where the dataset is actually `921 x 10161`. Can someone please explain how come we can do a 3-dimensional slicing? Thank you.

```
inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(10081,1))

layer1 = Conv1D(64,14)(inputs_1)
layer2 = layers.MaxPool1D(5)(layer1)
layer3 = Conv1D(64, 14)(layer2)
layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(layer3)

inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(4,))
layer5 = layers.concatenate([layer4, inputs_2])
layer6 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(layer5)
layer7 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(layer6)

model_2 = keras.models.Model(inputs = [inputs_1, inputs_2], output = [layer7])
model_2.summary()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.iloc[:,0:10085], df[['Result1','Result2']].values, test_size=0.2) 
X_train = X_train.to_numpy()
X_train = X_train.reshape([X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1])
X_train_1 = X_train[:,0:10081,:]
X_train_2 = X_train[:,10081:10085,:].reshape(736,4)

X_test = X_test.to_numpy()
X_test = X_test.reshape([X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1]) 
X_test_1 = X_test[:,0:10081,:]
X_test_2 = X_test[:,10081:10085,:].reshape(185,4)

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0005)
model_2.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = adam, metrics = ['acc'])
history = model_2.fit([X_train_1,X_train_2], y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 256, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that in both steps before you slice the variable is reshaped to have 3 dimensions:
`X_train = X_train.reshape([X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1])`, effectively adding one extra dimension in position 2

See Numpy's documentation for more info about `reshape`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Thank you Alexander. Could you please elaborate on how reshape is done using `[X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1]`?

Comment: Reshape is just changing the format/shape of your data, in this particular case you are taking the rows (921, shape[0]) and the columns (10,161 shape[1]) and effectively changing the matrix from a 2D to a 3D matrix. Which results in the shape [921, 10161, 1].

This is why you can then slice like this [:, 0:10081, :], where ':', indicates that you take all the values from those dimensions, and a select range from dimension (1)